# Is there any way to get the actual reading of a plot?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, plot, image-segmentation

I'm talking about getting the y-axis value of a point from the plot automatically or from code.

For example I have this point on plot:

[image]

If I am only interested in its y-axis I can use this code to get the y-axis value of this point back to my code:

```
dcm_obj = datacursormode(figure(1));
set(dcm_obj,'DisplayStyle','datatip',...
'SnapToDataVertex','off','Enable','on');
pause();
c_info = getCursorInfo(dcm_obj);
```

But the problem with this is that I have to manually intervene, use the `datacursormode`, and click on the point. Only then will the pixel be read and its y-value understood.

Is there anyway I can get this automatically? I mean the actual y-value from the plot without me intervening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>> h = plot((1:5).^2); %// example plot
>> get(h,'YData')
ans =
     1     4     9    16    25
```

Or, if the axis only has that one plot, you can get its handle dynamically:

```
>> plot((1:5).^2); %// example plot
>> get(get(gca,'Children'),'YData')
ans =
     1     4     9    16    25
```

Comment: Surely `get(get(gca, 'Children'), 'YData');`? I can't check either but it's the `line`/`scattergroup`/etc. you want, not the axes itself.

Comment: @Notlikethat You're right. You need a handle to the plot object

Comment: Thanks. Thats exactly what I was looking for. But if ``get(h, 'Ydata')`` and ``get(get(gca,'Children'),'YData')`` produce the same result then what is the difference between the two? Who use one over the other? What is ``Children``?

Comment: @FarazKhan I recommend the first: you get a handle to the plot object when you creat it, and then use that handle to refer to the object. The second approach can be used if you didn't store a handle: you ask the axis who its children are, and the axis reply is a vector of handles of the plot objects it contains.

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you for your helpful advice, the above method works well with simple plots but what do I do with the zoom level? I mean with a plot I have the y-values are what I need, but the y-values are between 0 and 20 of the x-axis. When zoomed out they appear to be a nice clean line, not disturbed by the x-axis distribution. The command you gave works perfectly on actual data, but my data is only represetive or relative when zoomed out. What can I do in that case. For example this: http://imgur.com/wAuwFGY. I'm sorry if I did not explain this properly, would really appreciate your input

Comment: @FarazKhan I only know how to get the actual `y` values of the plot. If what you want to do is to take the zoom into account, I'm afraid I can't be of much help with that